# How to read and edit MS Access file located in Cloud or in a Website using Python?

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

Let's say, I am in an environment where I can access and edit MS Access file but cannot download the file. The only option is that, I can work with the file Online using https server. Please let me know, if the file can be accessed and edited Online using Python. Thanks!